# Ubuntu loads off USB but won't install, also asks for username and password

Tags: boot, live-usb, 16.04

this is my first time here.
I have Ubuntu 13.04 running on my laptop and I read that it is longer supported which made me went ahead to download 16.04LTS. 
Using ubuntu's startupdisk creator, I mounted the ISO file on my USB and tried to boot from it.
When I click to either try without installing or to install, it takes me to the login screen and asks me to input username and then password. 
Meanwhile, I have never set any username and password for this Ubuntu (which I have not even installed).
I don't have access to any other thing on the laptop, like terminal when I can't even log in.
I have tried many different combinations that I saw online but no solution still.
I'm getting fed up with Ubuntu.
Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing but, maybe using the user and password of you current ubuntu installation where you created the bootable USB. Do you try to create again the installation USB?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have used the username and password of the current installation and it still doesn't work. I have also created the installation usb again twice. Still the same problem.

Comment: Well, I never heard anything like that. I think that probably the quicker solution is to build again the installation USB, maybe using other program. However, I hope someone can provide a different solution or explain something because I'm very interested.

Comment: I'm interested too .. i never created a disc with that program .. I have always used Windows and a program called Rufus .. I have never ran into this problem either and also am interested